# AlertDialog.Builder helper class cannot resolve constructor

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, helper

I've built a helper class to store various AlertDialog types. I thought it would be helpful so that I could call them anywhere in my code. Unfortunately I get an error below at `new AlertDialog.Builder()`. It says `` Cannot resolve constructor `Builder() ``. How can I get this to work?

```
public class AlertDialogHelper {

    public void showAboutDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder();
        builder.setTitle(R.string.about);
        builder.setMessage("A weather app made by Martin Erlic")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // Ok
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

}
```

In my activity:

```
private void showAboutAlertDialog() {
        AlertDialogHelper alertDialogHelper = new AlertDialogHelper();
        alertDialogHelper.showAboutDialog();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass a Context in the constructor like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

From your activity:

```
alertDialogHelper.showAboutDialog(this);
```

now:

```
public void showAboutDialog(Context context) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
public class AlertDialogHelper {

    public static Dialog CreateDialog(Context mContext) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.about);
        builder.setMessage("A weather app made by Martin Erlic")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // Ok
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

In my activity:

```
AlertDialogHelper.CreateDialog(this).show();
```